# cant' fix random position of buttons

Tags: android, button

i have myPopUp window... And there mini panel for buttons. But there when i added buttons... they added in random position (height -_-)[image]

see please on image and u can see this.

Can anyone help me fix it ?

here code  :

```
int xW = curWidth/5; ///width of my buttons 
        // xW=xW-100;
         Fullmain.addView(toolbar,curWidth-50,50);
         toolbar.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
         toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
         toolbar.addView(delete,xW,40);///delete,btnUp,btnGo,btnDown,btnOk - -my buttons)
         toolbar.addView(btnUp,xW,40);
         toolbar.addView(btnGo,xW,40);
         btnUp.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h1>&#9650;</h1>"));
         btnDown.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h1>&#9660;</h1>"));
         btnOk.setText("Save");
          toolbar.addView(btnDown,xW,40);
          toolbar.addView(btnOk,xW,40);
```

i never see this mmmm bug..  please tell me how to fix it

Comment: problem was in html.fromhtml("h1") .. very big size for small buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
toolbar.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```